# Multiple boot windows 8 and ubuntu how to remove?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, delete

I have a windows 8 and ubuntu 12 installed in my laptop but recently i formatted my laptop and re install windows and because i want a clean installation of my OS i erased and formatted the drive C again and continued installing windows.

After the installation done and the laptop booted up there is this option again which one i would like to boot?
So there is the windows 8 and the ubuntu again?

If i choose the ubuntu ofcourse there is nothing to boot up since i have erased the system  by formatting the drive C. So, I thought by reinstalling the Ubuntu OS again will solve the problem since it will overwrite  whatever is there.

But it became worst, there are 3 OS now... Windows 8, Ubuntu volume 1, Ubuntu volume 2.

Now i am confused. I dont want to mess up again with my system.. I dont want to remove the Ubuntu i installed i just dont like seeing the other one in there since the first ubuntu os that am trying to get rid doesn't work anyway.. If anybody could help me on regarding this matter it will be a big help for me..

By the way, I installed ubuntu using wubi..

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the My Computer icon on Windows 8-> Properties-> Advanced -> Startup and recovery -> Settings ... There decrease the time to list the os to zero from 30 seconds

Comment: Decreasing the time will not help.. The 3 OS is still there :( i want to use both OS its just that the other Ubuntu i previously installed is still on the list of OSs to choose from when booting..

Answer (score 0):

Use a Ubuntu liveCD to boot and install GRUB boot loader to your disk(`/dev/sda`).

use these commands :

```
sudo grub2-install /dev/sda
```

(this installs it in the mbr),

```
sudo update-grub2
```

(this updates the grub menu)

Comment: By the way, is there anyway to do that? I dont have Ubuntu live Cd since i do the installation using wubi.. Is there any other way?

Comment: i think Downloading ubuntu image is not a big problem. I missed one thing , before enter these commands you should mount all your partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Repairing the windows bootloader will remove unsed or unwanted boot entries.So bootup the windows installation disk and run the select **Repair your computer** option on the startup.Then select the *command prompt* option and run the below commands on it,

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

After that restart your pc,hope it will works.

Answer (score 0):

You should have deleted the partition on your hard drive and created a new one to get rid of the boot loader altogether.

Then install windows. If you haven't installed to much software into windows, I think it would be best to do that, instead of trying to repair things.

When installing windows, when you get to the choice of which partition to install to, below that there will be a box titled something like drive options, click that. It will give you the option to delete the partitions and create a new one.

There usually is a ntfs and a system reserved partition. Delete them both, and the ubuntu partition. Then create a new one using the entire drive.

You will get a message that windows will create the system reserve partition. Then choose the larger one to install to.

Windows install will create the new loader and format the partition automatically. Next install ubuntu if you want. It will do everything necessary to make things right.